# First and Last time with Night Labor time

Tags: postgresql

I have this issue.

These are the data that I have in the sample (I have more people and more times):

```
CREATE TABLE table_times(id,date_time,name)
AS ( VALUES
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-22 11:11'::timestamp without time zone, 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-22 11:43', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-22 11:48', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-22 11:54', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-22 17:52', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-23 08:13', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-23 08:28', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-23 10:25', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-23 10:25', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-23 10:25', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-23 13:30', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-24 22:20', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-24 23:27', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-25 03:14', 'Carlos Eduardo' ),
    ( 1000004, '2018-08-25 05:12', 'Carlos Eduardo' )
);
```

And I'm trying to find this:

```
id      start              end                  name
-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------   
1000004 2018-08-22 11:11:00 2018-08-22 17:52:00 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-23 08:13:00 2018-08-23 13:30:00 Carlos Eduardo
1000004 2018-08-24 22:20:00 2018-08-25 05:12:00 Carlos Eduardo
```

I need to organize these data per date, like the days 22, 23 and organize the time when start at night and finish at morning, like 24 and 25.

I have some other people and they don't have a specific labor time then I need to get the time by these data. Besides that, I have just these data to organize and the maximum of 14 labor hours per day.

I tried the query below, but when the labor time is at night, it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    MIN(date_time) AS start, 
    MAX(date_time) AS end, 
    name
FROM
    table_times
GROUP BY 
    id
    , name
    , EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_time)
    , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time)
    , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time)
ORDER BY name, start ASC
```

May anyone help me?

**PS:** Sorry my poor english.

Comment: I think at the very least you're going to have to give us exact shift definitions.  How late/early does a start time have to be to make it logically wrap over to the next day?

Comment: So, I don't have. Nowadays, the same employee can work for example, today from 05:00 until 15:00 and tomorrow starts 23:00 until 05:00 at post day. I don't have a rule. The person can work more than 15 hours if necessary. I'm trying to have just 2 record, one to start and one to finish. But in the same situation, without start and finish time.

Comment: Then it may not be possible to give you an exact answer.  Can we assume that a night shift would begin no _earlier_ than 22:00 and end no _later_ than 06:00?

Comment: I have given you a response below.  See if you can work with it.  At least, it does fit exactly with your sample data.

Comment: Nowadays I have these shifts: `05:00 til 15:00`, `06:00 til 16:00`, `07:00 til 17:00`, `08:00 til 18:00`, `09:00 til 19:00`, `11:00 til 21:00`, `13:00 til 23:00`, `18:00 til 04:00`, `19:00 til 05:00` and  `20:00 til 06:00`. But the same person can work in a different shift in differents days. I know that this issue is so confused, but I'm so confused too.

Comment: What happens if the names are different?

Comment: You mean the problem here is when you cross the midnight boundary, as if someone was working from like 11 PM to 1 AM? The only way to solve that is to assume that the check-in check-out times are paired when ordered by dates, is that a safe assumption?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: You also have an odd number of rows, so these aren't check-in ,check-out times.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I'm sorry. I'm late.
My problem is that I need to organize the first and the last interactions from the day. But, there will be cases that the employee will do a check-in at 11pm and the will do a check-out 3am, and in another day will do a check-in 8am and will do a check out 6pm. I can't predict his labor time.
It doesn't have a number of rows, can be pairs or not, because it would be a import excel data of time interactions, then the first record would be check-in and the last record would be check-out.
My PostgreSQL version is 9.1.

Comment: @EvanCarroll So, I tried to explain better here in http://rextester.com/JIWY68840
This is a real case of last month.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your problem tractable, we will need to define the boundaries for a shift.  In this answer, I assume that you have two kinds of shifts.  Day shifts, which start after 06:00 and end before 22:00, always occur within the same calendar day.  Night shifts, which start after 22:00 and end before 06:00, wrap around across two days.

I employ an accounting trick below, by which I treat all night shift timestamps as logically belonging to the same starting date.  This allows us to handle your boundary conditions.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        date_time,
        name,
        CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_time) >= 22 OR EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_time) <= 6
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS shift,
        CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM date_time) <= 6
             THEN date_time::date - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
             ELSE date_time::date END AS logical_date
    FROM table_times
)

SELECT
    id,
    MIN(date_time) AS start,
    MAX(date_time) AS end,
    name
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    id,
    shift,
    name,
    logical_date
ORDER BY
    name,
    start;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: To this case, when I can define a single shift, this works, but if work overtime or with others shifts, it don't works. Maybe my problem would be impossible to solve, but I don't expect this.

Comment: I'm not going to dance here and try to change my answer without concrete sample data.  I think you should be able to take my query and adapt it to what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry buddy. This is a real past example of last month: http://rextester.com/JIWY68840
It will just 2 records for each employee in each day. These records were input manually, but it will input dinamically like I questioned.